# speed up mysql query with group by

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query :

```
SELECT date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) as date,  
count(view) as views  
FROM ('table_1')  
WHERE 'address' = 1  
GROUP BY date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```

where

`view` : auto increment and primary key, (int(11))
`address` : index , (int(11))
`time` : index, (int(11))

total rows number of the table is : `270k`

this query have slow executing, in mysql-slow.log I got :

> Query_time: 1.839096
>   Lock_time: 0.000042
>   Rows_sent: 155
>   Rows_examined: 286435

with use `EXPLAIN` looks like below:

```
id      select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        Extra
1       SIMPLE          table_1     ref     address         address 5           const   139138      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

How to improve this query to speed up executing? Maybe better will be if I change date in PHP? But I think in PHP take a date as timestamp next convert to human readable and make "group by" will take more time then one query in MySQL.   
Maybe somebody knows how to make this query faster?

Comment: have you tried to remove FROM_UNIXTIME?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the functions  date() and FROM_UNIXTIME() to the time in the group by you kill any indexing benefit you may have on that field.

Adding a date column would be the only way i can see speeding this up if you need it grouped by day.  Without it, you'll need to decrase the overall set you are trying to group by.  You could maybe add start/end dates to limit the date range.  That would decrease the dates being transformed and grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding a additional `DATE` column to your table and indexing it.